# Read variable.def as string

Tags: python

I am trying to read variable.def as a string.

```
et.def?
Type:        str
String form: total energy
Length:      12
Docstring:
str(object='') -> string
```

when I try to access it:

```
et.def
  File "<ipython-input-60-028014709411>", line 1
    et.def
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

fails because Python assumes .def as a function definition. Is there any way to get the string part?

Comment: `getattr(et, 'def')`

Comment: what is `et` referring to?

Comment: @Padraic, et is a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python syntax includes several **reserved words** that look like identifiers but can't be used as such -- this includes `def` (and also `class`, `if`, and several others).

To access data (no doubt built from external sources?) that uses such identifiers **as** identifiers (e.g, in your case, apparently as an attribute name of whatever object `et` denotes), built-in functions `getattr`, `setattr`, &c, which accept the attribute name **as a string** (rather than as an identifier, as normal inline syntax does), come in handy (as they do whenever the attribute name is in a variable, etc).

So, in this case,

```
getattr(et, 'def')
```

should work for you in accessing that attribute's value.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Martelli, this solves the problem as 61612 suggested. The other alternative solution is to fix the problem at its root, meaning recompile the model that outputs variable definitions in reserved words. But this requires about a couple of more days of re-running my simulations or altering the netcdf outputs. I am interested in making some automated plots to analyze model output so this will come handy labeling the plots.

Comment: @GökhanSever, yes, there are cases in which avoiding reserved words takes time, and also ones in which it's just impossible -- because of a schema defined elsewhere, including such words, which just can't be altered because other code depends on them; in such cases, these not-too-dirty "tricks" come in handy.